# How does patch 1.04 affect mission payouts in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I read that the new GTA Online patch (1.04) reduces the payouts for missions.  How has the payout changed?

Comment: In the future, please use [gta-online], and not [grand-theft-auto-5], [multiplayer] AND [gta-online]. See the [meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7761/20306).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repeating missions now grants only half the original payment.

Comment: so you can repeat missions but you get only half the payout?

Comment: Yes. That is now the case.

Comment: what about RP?  also halved?

Comment: RP is not affected, seems.

Comment: In addition, if you are not the required level for a mission(ie you are level 30 and a level 60 person invites you to a level 60 mission) you only receive half of the payout.